# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python

Este programa en si lo que hace es graficar valores de sensores obtenidos de una base de datos en mysql, estoy tratando de mandar un email solo si el valor que viene de la base de datos es mayor que 25 pero me manda el error. Mi duda en si es como hacer la condición para que mande el correo tomando el valor que viene de la base de datos ('value').

Este es el código:

```
def update_graph(n):


dataSQL = [] 
X = deque(maxlen=10)    
Y = deque(maxlen=10)

sql_conn = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'DB')
cursor = sql_conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT value,timestamp FROM sensorParser where sensor='TC'")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    dataSQL.append(list(row))
    labels = ['value','timestamp']
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dataSQL, columns=labels)
    X = df['timestamp']
    Y = df['value']


data = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
        x=list(X),
        y=list(Y),
        name='TEMP',
        mode= 'lines+markers',

        )

if (df['value'] > 25):
    email = 'email@gmail.com'
    password = 'pass'
    send_to_email = 'email2@gmail.com'
    subject = 'ALERTA'
    message = 'Alerta'
    file_location = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\prograpython\\p.jpg'

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email
    msg['To'] = send_to_email
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

    filename = os.path.basename(file_location)
    attachment = open(file_location, "rb")
    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

    msg.attach(part)

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(email, send_to_email, text)
    server.quit()


return {'data': [data],'layout' : go.Layout(title="TEMPERATURA",xaxis={'title':'HORA/FECHA'},
                                            yaxis={'title':'°C'},)}
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (df['value'] > 25):
```

`df['value']` esta en forma de cadena de caracteres (String).

Deberias de evaluarlo y convertirlo a entero de la siguiente forma:

```
try:
        df['value'] = int(df['value'])
except Exception:
        df['value'] = algun_valor_por_defecto

if (df['value'] > 25):
```